# ¿Por qué mi slider no carga las imágenes?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, visual-studio, .net

Estoy intentando volver dinámico un slider si lo cargo de forma estatica todo funciona bien pero a la hora de usar razor no me carga las imagenes, pero si me carga las letras y el slider en general pero no se ve porque no aparecen las imagenes, sospecho que es porque para cargar las imagenes uso css.

Este es Javascript

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $('.slider-carousel').caroufredsel({
        responsive: true,
        width: '100%',
        circular: true,

        scroll:
            {
                items: 1,
                duration: 1500,
                pauseOnHover: true
            },

        auto: true,

        items:
            {
                visible:
                    {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 1
                    },

                height: "variable"
            }
    });
});
```

```css
Este es CSS

.img1 {
    background: url('../img/slider/1.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img2 {
    background: url('../img/slider/2.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
    background: url('../img/slider/3.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
Este es razor


@if(Model.VMRepositorioSlides != null)
{
    <div class="slider">
        @foreach(Slide slide in Model.VMRepositorioSlides.GetSlides())
        {
        <ul class="slider-carousel">
            <li class="@Model.VMSlide.claseSlide">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                   <h3>@Model.VMSlide.TituloSlide</h3>
                   <p class="texto-slider">@Model.VMSlide.DescripcionSlide</p>
                   <p class="rosa-bold">@Model.VMSlide.SpanSlide</p>
               </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Mi clase

```
public class Slide 
{ 
   public int IdSlide { get; set; } 
   public string TituloSlide { get; set; } 
   public string DescripcionSlide { get; set; } 
   public string SpanSlide { get; set; } 
   public string MostrarTextoSlide { get { return TituloSlide; } } 
   public string CoverSlide { get { return TituloSlide.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower() + ".png"; } } 
}
```

disculpen si lo que pregunto es muy ovbio, recien estoy empezando

Comment: A que tipo de letras te refieres cuando mencionas que las carga? Porque si te carga el titulo por ejemplo, quiere decir que los datos estan siendo obtenidos correctamente, pero como no muestra las imágenes puede haber un problema en como obtienes éstas (o en que nivel están)

Comment: si pasa que las imagenes las estoy cargando mediante una clase en css, pero creo que es mejor hacerlo con html osea razor y me creo un metodo Get, eso fue lo que hice pero el objeto me devuelve null y no se porque.. :(

Comment: Podrías incluir el código donde obtienes los datos?

Comment: si ahora lo edito y cargo la clase Slide

Comment: te lo puedo pasar por aqui y lo pegas en un bloc de notas? es que no estoy pudiendo editarla

Comment: public class Slide 
 {
  public int IdSlide { get; set; }
  public string TituloSlide { get; set; }
  public string DescripcionSlide { get; set; }
  public string SpanSlide { get; set; }

  public string MostrarTextoSlide
  {
   get { return TituloSlide; }
  }

  public string CoverSlide
  {
   get
   {
    return TituloSlide.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower() + ".png";
   }
  }
 }

Comment: la parte importante del codigo es esta:    public string CoverSlide { get { return TituloSlide.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower() + ".png"; } }

Comment: Me falta este método `Model.VMRepositorioSlides.GetSlides()`

Comment: quieres el codigo del repositorio de slides o de la vista?

Comment: Del repo... lo más probable es que ahí este el error, porque lo que me enviaste es simplemente una clase con atributos =/

Comment: el error estaba en como cargaba la imagen, ya las pude cargar pero ahora no me anda el slider sera xq estoy mesclando javascript que ahora me aparecen las 3 imagenes una arriba de la otra?

Comment: ya esta ahora si lo arregle con overflow hidden en css :)

Comment: Excelente.. deberias publicar la respuesta en caso que otras personas tengan el mismo problema!

Comment: de acuerdo ahora lo hago, es que no esta del todo arreglado, las imagenes si cargaron pero ahora no se mueve el slider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
@if(Model.VMRepositorioSlides != null)
{
    <div class="slider">
        @foreach(Slide slide in Model.VMRepositorioSlides.GetSlides())
        {
        <ul class="slider-carousel">
            <li class="img">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Slide", new { idSlide= slide.IdSlide})">
                    <img src="~/img/slider/@slide.CoverSlide" />
                </a>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>@slide.TituloSlide</h3>
                    <p class="texto-slider">@slide.DescripcionSlide</p>
                    <p class="rosa-bold">@slide.SpanSlide</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        }
    </div>
}
```